# How to drawtext with a color gradient fill with ffmpeg (ffmpeg-python)? and then mix with music?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, drawtext, ffmpeg-python

I'd like to achieve this result (to place a text with gradint or whatever picture-fill on top of a video):
[image]
So I decided to make a picture of gradient:
[image]
and then with chroma-key technique transform it to this (with transparent background):
[image]
and then place it over the video.

Here is the code with `ffmpeg-python`:

```
font_path = 'fonts/my_font.ttf'
input_video = ffmpeg.input('vid01.mp4')
split = input_video.filter_multi_output('split')
split_main = split[0]
split_txt_bg = split[1]

text_bg_black = ffmpeg.filter(text_bg, 'eq', brightness=-1000, saturation=0) # generate black bg from video input
text_mask = ffmpeg.filter(text_bg_black, 'drawtext', text='some text', fontcolor='0xFFFFFF', fontsize=85, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='68-(text_h/2)', fontfile=font_path) #draw text
text_mask_transparent = ffmpeg.filter(text_mask, 'colorkey', color='0xFFFFFF', similarity=0.45, blend=0.1)
text_on_bg = ffmpeg.filter([fill_gradient_gold, text_mask_transparent], 'overlay', x='(W-w)/2', y='(H-h)/2')
text = ffmpeg.filter(text_on_bg, 'colorkey', color='0x000000', similarity=0.45, blend=0.01)

comp1 = ffmpeg.filter([split_main, text], 'overlay', x='(W-w)/2', y='(H-h)/2')

comp.output('vid01_comp1.mp4').overwrite_output().run()
```

This solution works, BUT with problems:

1. in the final it lowers the brightness of original gradient picture, that I don't want at all
2. it doesn't seem to be elegant (cuz of chroma-keying solution)

Is it possible to make a alpha-mask with `drawtext` and then use it to cut the gradient?

It would be better if you provide the answer in `ffmpeg-python` cuz I'm a newbie and it's very hard for me to convert command-line `ffmpeg` to `ffmpeg-python`, thank you!

I also can't get how to mix resulting video `comp1` with music file, help pls.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026180/4516027) for your last question. You need to create video & audio streams and combine them together in the `output` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may draw the text on black background, and use `alphamerge` for creating transparent background with colored gradient text.
Then we can overlay the gradient (with the transparent background) on the input video.

I don't know if my suggested solution is the most elegant, but it is not lower the brightness of the gradient picture.

---

The suggested solution applies the following stages:

- Define synthetic black video source (1 frame).
- Draw white text on the black video frame.
- Add the "white text on black background" as alpha channel of the gradient image.
  Only the white text is opaque, and the black background is fully transparent.
- Overlay the above frame over the video.

---

Start by creating synthetic yellow video file (with sine audio) for testing:

```
# Build first synthetic video, for testing:
(
    ffmpeg
    .output(ffmpeg.input('sine=frequency=500', f='lavfi'),
            ffmpeg.input('color=yellow:size=1920x1080:rate=1', f='lavfi'),
            'in.mp4', vcodec='libx264', crf=17, pix_fmt='yuv444p', acodec='aac', ar=22050, t=10)
    .overwrite_output()
    .run()
)
```

---

Solution code sample:

```
import ffmpeg

# Example using FFmpeg CLI:
# ffmpeg -y -i text_bg.png -f lavfi -i color=0x505050:size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=1 -filter_complex "color=black[blk];[blk][0:v]scale2ref[b][v0];[b]drawtext=text='some text':fontcolor='0xFFFFFF':fontsize=300:x='(w-text_w)/2':y='(h-text_h)/2',format=gray[a];[v0][a]alphamerge[txt];[1:v][txt]overlay=format=yuv444" -frames:v 1 overlayed_text.png

input = ffmpeg.input('in.mp4')
input_video = input.video
input_audio = input.audio

bg = ffmpeg.input('text_bg.png').video  # Gradient image

blk = ffmpeg.input('color=black:size=1920x1080:rate=1:duration=1', f='lavfi').video  # Black background

# White text on black background - used as alpha channel
txt = blk.filter('drawtext', text='some text', fontcolor='0xFFFFFF', fontsize=400, x='(w-text_w)/2', y='(h-text_h)/2').filter('format', pix_fmts='gray')

# Add txt as alpha channel to bg - only the white text is opaque, the black background is transparent.
txt_on_bg = ffmpeg.filter([bg, txt], 'alphamerge')

# Overlay txt_on_bg on input_video
comp1 = ffmpeg.filter([input_video, txt_on_bg], 'overlay', x='(W-w)/2', y='(H-h)/2', format='yuv444')

ffmpeg.output(comp1, input_audio, 'vid01_comp1.mp4', vcodec='libx264', crf=17, pix_fmt='yuv444p', acodec='copy').overwrite_output().run()
```

---

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Nice and simple method, thank you!